# apt search does not work

Tags: apt, search

I run elementary  OS on my laptop and after I did the usual update and upgrade, `sudo apt search` stopped working. I've been looking everywhere for an answer and nobody seems to have had this problem!

When I type `sudo apt search <package>` the output is the usual "sorting ..." but it stops at 1% and doesn't say anything.

I've tried so far: `apt-get clean`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get -f install`; but none seem to be helpful.

Funny thing, I am able to search for packages on the Software Center, and `apt-get install` also works. So, I don't know what could be causing this.

Please, I need your help! I'm at your disposal and willing to try whatever you think will help me **get apt search work again**!

Comment: `apt-get install` works, right? If yes, try doing `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then `sudo aptitude`. See if that works.

Comment: @MagnusTeekivi but isn't aptitude another package manager? I apologise if I'm wrong in that asumption -I'm still very new to this whole thing, but I'm trying!-; but I would love to be able to just keep using apt. Or at least understand what's the problem behind apt search not working and if there is a way I can fix it! I really apreciate that you took the time to answer!

Comment: aptitude should be a console graphical frontend to apt-get and co.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` is not really related to the traditional `apt-something` commands, it's another application. `apt search` means you started the application `apt` with the parameter `search`. As far as I know `apt` is under active development and most likely unstable in Ubuntu 14.04. To search the cache for packages, you should use `apt-cache search`.